# "Could not activate JNI Handle..." при отладке Android приложения

Tags: android, c#, visual-studio, xamarin

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что это за ошибка и как с ней бороться ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возникает при попытке отладки проекта через usb на телефоне (ASUS, Android 4.2 - API 17). Предоставлю дополнительную информацию если требуется.